# Difficulties understanding a problem related to the law of total probability

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

> A student realizes during the class that the charger for his laptop is missing.
>
> With a $\frac{1}{2} : \frac{1}{4} : \frac{1}{4}$ ratio the charger is at home, at the library, or was left in the train on the way school.
>
> Further, the chances to find the charger at the library are $90$% and to find the charger in the train on the way home are $50$%.
>
> What are the probabilities to find the charger
>
> 1. At the library and
> 2. in the train.

I have some doubts regarding this problem.

> First, what does it mean here the ratio $\frac{1}{2} : \frac{1}{4} : \frac{1}{4}$? Does it mean that the probability of having left the charger at home, at the library and in the train is respectively $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$

They sum up to $1$, so this could make sense, but I am not sure...

Another problem that I have is:

> What is the difference between the chances and the probabilities I need to find? And therefore what exactly are the chances given here?

My interpretation of these chances is related to the conditional probability, that is I think that, for example, $90$% is the conditional probability of finding the charger at the library given that we left it at the library.

If this is correct, they could be asking us to find the intersection between having left the charger at the library and the fact of finding the charger, that is

$$P(L_L \cap F) = P(L_L) \cdot P(F \mid L_L)$$

Where $L_L$ is the event of having left the charger at the library.

I feel like I am saying a lot of stupid things.

I have read little about the law of total probability, but I am not sure If have to apply it here actually (this is just part of the problem and I guess I need to apply it later).

Could you please help me in understanding the problem?

(Note that I am not asking for a solution to the problem, but just to help me to understand the problem and thus lead me in the right direction)

Comment: You are not saying stupid things.  Your expression for the probability of finding the charger at the library is correct for the reasons you give and so will give you an answer to that part of the question of $0.225$ (multiply by $100$ if you want a percentage)

Comment: The wording is very informal, so requires interpretation. Your interpretation is I think the reasonable one.

Comment: Yes, and yes. Apparently the probability the charger was left at home was $\frac12$, so if you are certain to find it there if it was lost there, then the probability of finding it anywhere is $\frac14\times \frac9{10}+\frac14\times \frac12+\frac12\times 1$

Comment: Indeed$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $